# Instantiate a Python class from a name

Tags: python

So i have a set of classes and a string with one of the class names. How do I instantiate a class based on that string?

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, left, right):
     self.left = left
     self.right = right

str = "foo"
x = Init(str, A, B)
```

I want x to be an instantiation of class foo.

Comment: Duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734970/python-reference-to-a-class-from-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176136/convert-string-to-python-class-object, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you know the namespace involved, you can use it directly -- for example, if all classes are in module `zap`, the dictionary `vars(zap)` is that namespace; if they're all in the current module, `globals()` is probably the handiest way to get that dictionary.

If the classes are not all in the same namespace, then building an "artificial" namespace (a dedicated dict with class names as keys and class objects as values), as @Ignacio suggests, is probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 31):

In your case you can use something like:

```
get_class = lambda x: globals()[x]
c = get_class("foo")
```

And it's even easier to get the class from the module:

```
import somemodule
getattr(somemodule, "SomeClass")
```

Answer (score 8):

```
classdict = {'foo': foo}

x = classdict['foo'](A, B)
```

Comment: How can I do it using reflection?

Comment: You *could* use `getattr()`, but that could expose you to security problems. Using a class decorator will let you enumerate classes automatically, but those only exist in newer versions of Python.

Comment: How would you use the decorator? Would it append to a list of instantiable classes - and I would have to iterate through this list to pick the correct class to instantiate?

Comment: @UtkarshSinha: ... No, it would add an entry to `classdict`.

Answer (score 6):

```
classname = "Foo"
foo = vars()[classname](Bar, 0, 4)
```

Or perhaps

```
def mkinst(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return globals()[cls](*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        raise NameError("Class %s is not defined" % cls)

x = mkinst("Foo", bar, 0, 4, disc="bust")
y = mkinst("Bar", foo, batman="robin")
```

Miscellaneous notes on the snippet:

`*args` and `**kwargs` are special parameters in Python, they mean «an array of non-keyword args» and «a dict of keyword args» accordingly.

PEP-8 (official Python style guide) recommends using `cls` for class variables.

`vars()` returns a dict of variables defined in the local scope.

`globals()` returns a dict of variables currently present in the environment outside of local scope.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
cls = __import__('cls_name')
```

and this - http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm maybe helpful

Answer (score 0):

You might consider usage of metaclass as well:

```
Cls = type('foo', (), foo.__dict__)
x = Cls(A, B)
```

Yet it creates another similar class.