# Class from variable

Tags: python, class, object, new-operator

I have a class, trying to instantiate another class, based off of a variable name passed to it. It is complaining that 'str' object is not callable. What is the proper way to do this?

```
def MyClass:
    def __init__(self, otherName):
        self.other = otherName()
```

EDIT: Here is the entirety of my code, is there anything I should do differently? Is eval evil in Python?

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                      

class Model:
    def get_post(self, id):
        # Would query database, perhaps                                                                                                                                                
        return {"title": "Python :: Test Page", "body": "Test page using Python!"}

class Controller:
    def __init__(self, viewName):
        self.model = Model()
        self.view = viewName()

    def main(self):
        post = self.model.get_post(1)
        self.view.display(post)

class View:
    def header(self, item):
        print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
        print "<html>"
        print "<head>"
        print "<title>%(title)s</title>" % item
        print "</head>"
        print "<body>"

    def footer(self, item):
        print "</body>"
        print "</html>"

class Blog(View):
    def display(self,item):
 View.header(self,item)
 print "<p>%(body)s</p>" % item
 View.footer(self,item)

c = Controller(Blog)
c.main()
```

Comment: The proper way to do this is to search on SO for this question, which has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553784/can-you-use-a-string-to-instantiate-a-class-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Reference to a class from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734970/python-reference-to-a-class-from-a-string)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452969/does-python-have-an-equivalent-to-java-class-forname/452971#452971) is probably what you're looking for...

Comment: Don't you think showing us how you're trying to instantiate MyClass() would be important here? And also __init() isn't a constructor.

Comment: @Falmarri I forgot the trailing __, and I'm simply doing: m = myClass("Blog")

Comment: Uh... your code as posted works (once I fix the indentation in the Blog class), and I don't see where you are using, nor propose to use, `eval`.

Comment: "is eval evil in Python?" No.  It's usually a waste of keystrokes.  Please read @Greg Hewgill's answer.  You don't need `eval`.  So don't waste time typing it, the ()'s and the "'s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this *without* using strings at all. You can refer to classes in Python by name, and pass them around just like any other object. So, using your definition of `MyClass` above, instead of doing:

```
c = Controller("Blog")
```

you can use simply:

```
c = Controller(Blog)
```

Using `eval()` for something like this is definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get to your class through the dict that the locals() function returns.  Here is a simple class,

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word

    def __str__(self):
        return "Class A word is '%s'" % self.word
```

I can create this class from a string of its name, and call it normally,

```
>>> myclass = locals()['ClassA']('wibble')
>>> print myclass
Class A word is 'wibble'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really would like to pass the parameter as a string, you could use eval().

```
class MyClass: 
    def __init(self, otherName): 
        self.other = eval(otherName)()
```

Comment: Using `eval` should be a last resort.

Comment: `eval` generally leads to wierd unreproducable bugs and should be avoided in nearly all cases. Python gives great flexibility to do kooky metaprogramming without resorting to literal evaluation of constructed code.