# Given an instance of a type object, how do you call the constructor of the class (equivalent of GetConstructor in other languages)

Tags: python, class, reflection, constructor

It seems simple, but I can't figure out how to get a class constructor if given only a type.
For clarity I created a code snippet demonstrating the problem as a function stub.

Google is not turning up anything useful, maybe I can't find the right keywords to avoid the SEO driving me to popular intro to python sites.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Person(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    age: int

def magic_thing_maker(the_type, ctor_args):
    pass # I am stuck with what to do here

some_type = type(Person)
the_person = magic_thing_maker(some_type, {'name':'Saul Goodman', 
'age':37})

assert (the_person == Person('Saul Goodman', 37))
```

Feel free to call my unpythonic for asking this; I get that asking this question indicates I should seek healthier approaches to the problem at hand.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `type(Person)` is `type`, you could use the class name as alternative. The class can be instantiated from [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), using the [**-operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to pass the dictionary to the constructor. Here is an example:

```
def magic_thing_maker(the_type, ctor_args):
    return globals()[the_type](**ctor_args)

some_type = Person.__name__
the_person = magic_thing_maker(some_type, {'name':'Saul Goodman',
'age':37})
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734970/python-reference-to-a-class-from-a-string) for further information.
For instantiating classes from imported modules, you can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#getattr), see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821104/dynamic-instantiation-from-string-name-of-a-class-in-dynamically-imported-module).